# Problems updating digital clock widget in PyQt4 - calling slot and signal

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

Ok so this is an edited version of my previous post. I am trying to place a digital clock onto a home window. I am having difficulty updating the value. I saw a tutorial [1](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?key=QLCDNumberDigitalClock&index=409) that called a method with @pyqtSlot() in a different class but because I am working in the main window class, I was not able to call this and the clock did not appear at all. The following code below brings up the current time but the clock is not updated:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        lcdNumber = QLCDNumber(self)
        timer = QTimer()
        lcdNumber.setDigitCount(8)
        self.showTime(lcdNumber)
        lcdNumber.connect(timer,SIGNAL("timeout()"),lcdNumber,SLOT("showTime()"))
        timer.start(1000)
        self.show()


    @pyqtSlot()
    def showTime(self,lcdNumber):
        lcdNumber.display(QTime.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"))


def run():    
        app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        GUI = Window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I found a work around using some code I found [here](http://thecodeinn.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/tutorial-pyqt-digital-clock.html) but I am still unsure how to get the signal and slot functions operational.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

from time import strftime

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50,50,700,300)
        self.home()

    def home(self):

        self.timer =QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Time)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.lcd.display(strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S"))
        self.lcd.setDigitCount(8)

        self.show()

    def Time(self):
        self.lcd.display(strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S"))     


def run():    
        app=QApplication(sys.argv)
        GUI = Window()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Comment: Your solution here is entirely correct - I certainly wouldn't describe it as a "work around". The reason why it works (compared to the original example), is because it keeps references to `lcd` and `timer`. It's also good that you've avoided old-style signal and slot connections (which can be very error-prone).

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for your comment, This approach does also seem a lot more straightforward the one I was asking about.